# Error: Invalid volume specification in docker compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am facing below mentioned error, could you please help me to resolve this?

```
invalid volume specification: '/run/desktop/mnt/host/d/Master/Projects/python_task/image: /app:rw': invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: ' /app' mount path must be absolute
```

My file structure could be seen here [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eKG2.png)

Docker-Compose:

```yaml
services:

  psql_crxdb:

    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=dvd_rental
    volumes:
      - "./dvdrental_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"


  pgadmin:

    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com 
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - "8080:80"


  analytics:

    build:
      context: main
    environment:
      POSTGRESQL_CS: 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@psql_crxdb:5432/dvd_rental'
    depends_on:
      - psql_crxdb
    command: ["python", "./main.py" ]

  pythontask:

    build:
      context: python_task
    command: ["python", "./circle.py" ]
    volumes:
      - "./python_task/image: /app"
```

Dockerfile:

```bash
FROM python:3.9

RUN apt-get install wget
RUN pip install Pillow datetime
WORKDIR /app
COPY circle.py circle.py

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "circle.py"]
```

Comment: In the very last line of `docker-compose.yml`, there's an extra space before `/app` that causes this error.  I'd suggest deleting that `volumes:` block entirely, though, since the application code is built into the image and that mount hides it.

Comment: Thanks, it has helped to resolve the issue. About deleting volumes, actually I need to save the  circle image so that's why I thought it's necessary to have volumes.